# Eclipse keeps hanging when it tries to upload my Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, java

I have recently been creating Android application and I have come to a halt. I am following through on The New Boston's Tutorials, and I got to Ep. 13 when I got this:

```
[2013-05-26 19:24:06 - Android Testing App] ------------------------------
[2013-05-26 19:24:06 - Android Testing App] Android Launch!
[2013-05-26 19:24:06 - Android Testing App] adb is running normally.
2013-05-26 19:24:06 - Android Testing App] Performing com.heyawesomepeople.testing.Splash activity launch
[2013-05-26 19:24:07 - Android Testing App] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'droidX'
[2013-05-26 19:24:07 - Android Testing App] Uploading Android Testing App.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
```

The Emulator is open before I run. It just sits there and hangs. This is what my manifast looks like: http://pastie.org/7966092
I have tried many things. All including restarting Eclipse, Cleaning, and bumping up my TimeOut time.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Can you post some of your code like the `onCreaste()` at least of your launcher `Activity` and what the logcat says? Also, have you tried running on a real device, this is generally better

Comment: just delete that avd and create again..before run ur app..start the avd.?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Eclipse are you using? I was using Indigo, then I updated to ADT. The emulator has been running better for my Android apps since then.

Comment: ADT, ADT is an android development plugin. Wheres that? I have an Eclipse file from about 4-6 months ago. It's Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new Android Virtual Device (AVD) and try again with the new device create by you.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest seems to be ok, minsdk and target are both the same (10), you should always build in the latest. Are you sure your avd is Api 10?

Try updating your adt plugin and sdk manager tools. Delete your avd and create another one.